# Ubuntu - Can't install deb package

Tags: linux, ubuntu

everyone.
I want to install a deb package.
I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9dT1.png)

After that, I tried:
https://askubuntu.com/a/40050

It helped to deal with some dependencies, but not all.
Then, I've tried:
https://askubuntu.com/a/40037

But I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ab2.png)

And now I can't even delete package, as I tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1001828

Solution, which I see is: delete package to install gdebi-core, to get missing dependencies, to be able to install this package again, but fully as now it isn't working.
Or is there something, that I am missing?
Thank you

Comment: Please add your code and error(s) between triple back-cotes (\`\`\`...\`\`\`). No image. Thanks

Comment: ! Images : https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text ............... Install packages with apt : The first command is always `sudo apt update` ..... Then you can get the missing dependencies : I.e. the package list must always be up to date .